# Why after I run my code , appear undefined:returnAllSMSBlasts , so my function not working why?

Tags: go

I Make Restful api , I want display result , but  golang say error about function , error say "undefined: returnAllSMSBlasts" why , can you check my code error ?

this my code

**data.go**

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func returnAllSMSBlasts(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)  {
    var smsblasts SMSBlasts
    var arr_smsblast []SMSBlasts
    var response Response

    db := connect()
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("Select SequenceID,MobilePhone,Output,WillBeSentDate,SentDate,Status,DtmUpd")
    if err != nil{
        log.Print(err)
    }

    for rows.Next(){
        if err := rows.Scan(&smsblasts.SequenceID, &smsblasts.MobilePhone,
            &smsblasts.Output, &smsblasts.WillBeSentDate,
            &smsblasts.SentDate, &smsblasts.Status,
            &smsblasts.DtmUpd); err != nil{
                log.Fatal(err.Error())
        }else{
            arr_smsblast = append(arr_smsblast , smsblasts)
        }
        }
    response.Status = 1
    response.Message = "success"
    response.Data = arr_smsblast

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
}
```

and this my code

**main.go**

```
    package main

    import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/denisenkom/go-mssqldb"
)


    func main() {

        router := mux.NewRouter()
        router.HandleFunc("/postsmsblasts", returnAllSMSBlasts).Methods("POST")
        http.Handle("/", router)
        fmt.Println("Connected to port 1234")
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1234", router))

    }
```

Comment: Code looks fine. Did you forget to save data.go? Or show how do you try to compile the app.

Comment: I have save data.go when I run appear like this : https://imgur.com/a/Ngpm5lm @SergioTulentsev

Comment: What is the __command__? Try building/running from terminal, not vscode.

Comment: when I run, it produces an exe file, so I run exe, but I test with postman, saying that page 404 is not found, and I type it in a column like this localhost: 1234 / postsmsblasts, but display empty result @SergioTulentsev, something wrong with my code ?

Comment: In Postman, you're selecting POST type of request, right?

Comment: yes, @SergioTulentsev , but still get 404 page not found